# Parametric expressions

Tags: calculus

I would like your quidance to write the parametric expressions of the linear route A-->B-->C, for A(-2,3), B(2,-3),C(3,5), in that way so that the parameter t is 0<=t<=2.

I tried to write that the linear route A-->B has parametric expressions:
x(t) = - 2+[2-(-2)]t
y(t)=3+(-3-3)t
but I am not quite sure if my way of thinking is the correct one.

Comment: Yes, it is correct for A and B. But point C does not lie on the line.

Comment: Thank you very much. However in case We would like to check our results, for t=2, the expressions above lead us to the results that x=-2+8=6 and y=3-12=-9, and not to the coordinates of point B. Am I thinking right?

Comment: If you let $t=1$, then you will get point B. In order to get point B for $t=2$, you can scale the slopes with $\frac{1}{2}$, yielding $x(t)=-2+2t$ and $y(t)=3-3t$.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: You’re welcome!

Comment: Could you provide me with your quidance for the line BC as well? Because the formula I use, leads me to find the parametrization only for the case 0<=t<=1. But here it asks to do the parametrization of BC when 0<=t<=2. Thank you very much.

Comment: Well, if you again scale the slopes with $\frac{1}{2}$, it should be right.